# Real time physics body scaling issue in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

my goal is to create a platform, from one x,y coordinate, to the touch event, in such a way that sliding your finger around will move and resize the platform in real time. However the problem is, that if there is a ball on said platform, and i then move the platform, The ball will freeze and stop acting like a ball, until the platform is done being manipulated.

Is there a way that I can get the balls to continue to behave as normal even while the platform they are on is being moved?

I have included the code so you can play with it and see what I mean. The best way to see what I am talking about is to click to create a platform, wait for a ball to land on it, and then drag the end of the platform around.

```
        local physics = require("physics");
physics.start();
physics.setDrawMode("hybrid");
W = display.contentWidth;
H = display.contentHeight;

balls = {};

local function createPlatform(event)
    if (event.phase == "began") then
        if(line) then
            line.parent:remove(line);
        end
        x = (event.x - (W/2 - 80));
        y = (event.y - (H/2));
        line = display.newLine(W/2 - 80, H/2, event.x, event.y)
        line.width = 5;
        physics.addBody(line, "static", {shape = {0, 0, x, y}});
        line.isBullet = true;
    end
    if (event.phase == "moved") then
        x = (event.x - (W/2 - 80));
        y = (event.y - (H/2));
        if (line) then
            line.parent:remove(line);
        end
        line = display.newLine(W/2 - 80, H/2, event.x, event.y)
        line.width = 5;
        physics.addBody(line, "static", {shape = {0, 0, x, y}});
        line.isBullet = true;
    end
    if (event.phase == "ended") then

    end
end

local function spawnBalls(event)

    i = 1;
    local function spawnb(event)
        rand = math.random(1, 4);
            if (rand == 1) then
                balls[i] = display.newCircle(math.random(140, 180), -30, 7.5);
                balls[i]:setFillColor(255,0,0);
                physics.addBody(balls[i], {radius = 7.5})
                balls[i].isBullet = true;
                i = i + 1;
                rand = math.random(1,4)
            elseif (rand == 2) then
                balls[i] = display.newCircle(math.random(140, 180), -30, 7.5);
                balls[i]:setFillColor(0, 255, 0);
                physics.addBody(balls[i], {radius = 7.5})
                balls[i].isBullet = true;
                i = i + 1;
                rand = math.random(1,4)
            elseif (rand == 3) then
                balls[i] = display.newCircle(math.random(140, 180), -30, 7.5);
                balls[i]:setFillColor(0, 0, 255)
                physics.addBody(balls[i], {radius = 7.5})
                balls[i].isBullet = true;
                i = i + 1;
                rand = math.random(1,4)
            elseif (rand == 4) then
                balls[i] = display.newCircle(math.random(140, 180), -30, 7.5);
                balls[i]:setFillColor(255, 255, 0);
                physics.addBody(balls[i], {radius = 7.5})
                balls[i].isBullet = true;
                i = i + 1;
                rand = math.random(1,4)
            end
        end
    timer.performWithDelay(1500, spawnb, -1);
end

spawnBalls();

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", createPlatform)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you remove the body (line) before Box2D has a chance to calculate new positions/velocities for bodies (when moving your finger, mouse on screen) ... you could try increasing  position iterations and frame rate...but this is not really recommended due to performance loss.
I would recommend rotating and scalling the body with out removing it and and adding a new one. You can use .rotation and .xScale/.yScale.

Haven't tried it but this is how I would do it.
I'm kind of new to Corona too...so no guarantees.

Comment: @lansen No such luck. Using rotation, and not deleting the physics body still yields the same behavior. The position and velocity stop calculating until the platform is not longer moving, and then the ball begins to behave normally again. This happens even while increasing the position/velocity iterations

Comment: Try... not making the line a body. Then test if any ball hits it and apply a force to it (simulate it hitting the line).

Comment: That would work for the inital hit...but then It would get very complicated keeping it on the line as if its rolling on a physics body...unless perhaps I say

       if (event.phase = "began") then
             ball[i]:applyForce(0, -0.5);
        end

which essentially applys such a small force to get it barely off the line, but then immediately falls back and touches it again, and repeats. Ill play around with it